# Rake wall for "flat" roof structure - any way to do it yet maintain consistent stud heights?

Tags: framing, roof, construction

I'm working on a flat top roof structure, but was advised at the end of https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/262338/135898 to at least keep it to a 1/8-in to 1/4-in per foot slope rather than being perfectly flat.  If I were to go this route is there a proper way to do it that avoids the need to trim all studs to create rake walls?

Perhaps I rip the roof joists to create this angle? They are 2x8s planned at 16" OC, so I think may be overengineered as is.  If doing, that I'd probably just rip the ones that are fully on the top plates and maybe notch the others that are over the span.  This is for a 12x10 flat-top treehouse.

Comment: Just really need to raise the high end, probably by adding an extra 2x4 plate on top of the back wall.  The open space on the side walls can be filled in or just covered over.  A 2x will give an inch and a half rise, just a touch more than 1/8 per foot slope(10 feet).

Comment: It would probably be less overall effort to trim the studs than to rip two joists full-length and birdsmouth the rest.